# Is there efficient way to map graph onto blocks in CUDA programming?

Tags: cuda, gpu

In parallel computing, it is usually the first step to divide the origin problem into some sub-task and map them onto blocks and threads.

For problems with regular data structure, it is very easy and efficient, for example, matrix multiplication, FFT and so on.

But graph theory problems like shortest path, graph traversal, tree search, have irregular data structure. It seems not easy, at least in my mind, to partition the problem onto blocks and threads when using GPU.

I am wondering if there efficient solutions for this kind of partition?

For simplicity, take single-source shortest-path problem as a example. I am stuck at how to divide the graph so that both locality and coalescing.

Comment: That is a very broad question that will be very hard to answer. Did you have a particular application in mind? Could you refine the scope of what you are asking about?

Comment: Could you say more about sphere of application of algorithms you are looking for. I can share experiences in nearest neighbor search but I can't be helpful If you ask about some general graph problem like spanning tree search...

Comment: @marina.k  I am not working at a single-source shortest path problem. Firstly, it seems that Dijkstra algorithm is hard if realized in many-core system. Second, if using a iteration solution similar to Dijkstra algorithm, because of the constraint between nodes are very complex and irregular, it is hard to ensure  locality and coalescing, even to use shared memory to cache.

Comment: @talonmies please see the comment posted above.

Answer (score 1):

The tree data structure is designed to best optimize the sequential way of progressing. In tree search, since each state is highly dependent on the previous state, I think it would not be optimal to parallelize traversal on tree.

As far as the graph is concerned, each connected node can be analyzed in parallel, but I guess there might be redundant operations for overlapping paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapGraph which uses GAS method for all the things u mentioned....they also have some example implemented for the same and Library included for Gather, Apply and Scatter in cuda for GPU and cpu only implementation also.

You can find latest version here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpgraph/files/0.3.3/